# Getting around the 4GB JAR limit

Tags: java, image, offline

I'm making a offline database program that happens to include a lot of images - enough to make the jar file over 4GB, which, as Netbeans tells me, is not permitted.

I would like to know what the best way of getting my files under this limit might be, and how to program in methods to access the images with Java. The image folder is currently 4.63GB by itself and will get larger (by maybe a few MBs) in future updates.

What do you suggest, Stackoverflow?

Comment: One thing you could do is to remove all unnecessary images and make your app lighter. Are those images really needed?

Comment: Distribute your images differently? Maybe an installer that puts the images on the external filesystem; then you might read the images from there.

Comment: @BackSlash I probably can reduce the size a bit, I'll try that first.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Where should it be installed? Is there a preferred directory on each operating system for application resources?

Comment: @NathanielD.Hoffman That's up to you, and yes most operating systems has a different preferred directory (and end-users also usually have opinions on the matter). You could make it selectable, and read a configuration parameter on startup.

Comment: Isn't it something like `C:/Program Files(x86)/<YourProgram>` for windows, and `/usr/bin` (for the binary, and other related dirs) for Unix? Either way, having the user be able to choose where they want it is good, and then your program could look for a registry entry or path or something similar depending on the OS.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like it'll work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create multiple jars. Why does it have to be one single jar?

Also starting with Java 1.7.0 build 55 Java supports jars and zip files larger than 4GB, see this post:

[**ZIP64, The Format for > 4G Zipfile, Is Now Supported**](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/zip64_support_for_4g_zipfile)

You can also compress the images, use a different format which compresses them to smaller size so altogether they will be less than 4GB; consider lossy compression like JPEG. If they are already maximum compressed, then you may consider decreasing their dimensions (e.g. 500x250 pixels instead of 1000x500).

**Edit:**

Quoting form the javadoc of [`java.util.zip` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html):

> An implementation may optionally support the ZIP64(tm) format extensions defined by the PKWARE ZIP File Format Specification. The ZIP64(tm) format extensions are used to overcome the size limitations of the original ZIP format.

So it looks it's up to the java implementation whether it supports Zip64, it is not a specification requirement. The first link suggests though that OpenJDK supports it.

Also Googleing around a bit it looks all Oracle JDKs support it after the mentioned release (1.7.0 b55). Netbeans might deny to create jars larger than 4 GB if it's an old version or because it wants to keep compatibility with older JVMs.

**How to tell if your Java supports it?**

In case of Oracle JRE/JDK: Look for the `rt.jar` (runtime.jar) file of the JRE/JDK. Open it (it's a zip file) and go into the `java/util/zip` folder. If it has a `ZipConstants64.class` file, then it has support for Zip64.

From Java code: try to acquire the [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object for the mentioned class. If it succeeds, your Oracle JRE/JDK supports it:

```
System.out.println("Java version: " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println("Java vendor: " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
try {
    Class.forName("java.util.zip.ZipConstants64");
    System.out.println("Your Java supports Zip64 :)");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Your Java doesn't support Zip64 :(");
}
```

Output:

```
Java version: 1.8.0_20
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Your Java supports Zip64 :)
```

Comment: I've never heard of using multiple jars...I'll have to look that one up. Also, is there something I need to do with Netbeans to get ZIP64 to work? I'm up to date on Java and I'm still told the jar is over the 4GB limit.

Comment: @NathanielD.Hoffman Googleing around a bit it looks all Oracle JDKs support it after the mentioned release (1.7.0 b55). Netbeans might deny to create jars larger than 4 GB if it's an old version or because it wants to keep compatibility with older JVMs.

Comment: jdk-1.8.0_91 still have this "java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 4255330019 but got 594391 bytes)" error while openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0 is ok.